# C# WPF MjpegStream. video appears to pause when writing and reading data on TCP/IP packets

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

My window should display the status of the video stream
and the data sent and received in tcpip.

Every two seconds, the video appears to pause
when writing and reading data on TCP/IP.
How can we solve this phenomenon?

For your information,
The application programs that deal with video stream,
the stream look natural regardless of the tcpip I send and receive.

```
enter code here

private MJPEGStream m_Stream;
private DispatcherTimer m_Timer = null;

public TcpClient clientTcp = new TcpClient;
public NetworkStream streamTcp = new NetworkStream;


public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    IpCamera();
    OpenTcpIpCommuncation();
    
}




public void OpenTcpIpCommuncation()
{
    var result= clientTcp.BeginConnect("192.168.0.3","24", null, null);

    
    streamTcp = clientTcp.GetStream();
    
    
    
    m_Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    m_Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0);    
    m_Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TcpTimer_Tick);
    m_Timer.Start();
    
}

 private void TcpTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    for (int=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        stream.Write(send_status_packet, 0, Length);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        NumberOfBytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    

   // label, text etc  upate from data

}




public void IpCamera()
{

    
    string sUrl = "http://192.168.0.100:8080" "//" + kCameraInfo.SubUrl;
    m_Stream = new MJPEGStream(sUrl);
    m_Stream.Login = "admin";
    m_Stream.Password = "1234";
    m_Stream.NewFrame += Camera_Frame;
    m_Stream.Start();
}


private void Camera_Frame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{

    try
    {
        BitmapImage bi;
        using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone())
        {
            bi = bitmap.ToBitmapImage();
        }

        bi.Freeze(); 
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { imgCamera.Source = bi; }));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep` blocks the UI thread.

Not sure why exactly you have this `for` loop, but it blocks the UI thread for at least 20 * 50 milliseconds, i.e. one second.

As a workaround, you may declare the Tick event handler async and use `Task.Delay` instead. You may perhaps also use the async versions of the Write and Read methods:

```
private async void TcpTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(send_status_packet, 0, Length);
        await Task.Delay(50);
        NumberOfBytes = await stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    ...
}
```

It might also be better not have the loop at all, and run the timer at a shorter interval.